# Insert incremented ID from the tbl_project to tbl_expense it must have same ID. I use PKey & Fkey the ID must be returned

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

There is no error in this code. The only concern I face is when I try to save in the database the FK won't get the id of PK. I already setup my database relationship and it connect id - projectid.

```
if (textID.Text == "" && textProject.Text == "" && textAmount.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Details..!");
}
else
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_project WHERE Contract_ID = '" + textID.Text + "'", conn);
    DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(datatbl);
    if (datatbl.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Contract ID Already Exist!!");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adap1 = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO tbl_project(Contract_ID,Contract_Amount,Contractor,Project_Name,Start_Date,End_Date,Year,Address,Remarks,Status)VALUES('" + textID.Text + "','" + textAmount.Text + "','" + textContract.Text + "','" + textProject.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date + "','" + textYear.Text + "','" + textAddress.Text + "','" + textOthers.Text + "','" + comboBox5.Text + "')", conn);
        DataTable fill1 = new DataTable();
        adap1.Fill(fill1);
        SqlDataAdapter adap2 = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO tbl_expense(CONTRACT,CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACTOR,PROJECT_STATUS,COVERED_PERIOD,END_PERIOD,PROJECT_AMOUNT)VALUES('" + textProject.Text + "','" + textID.Text + "','" + textContract.Text + "','" + comboBox5.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date + "','" + textAmount.Text + "')", conn);
        DataTable data2 = new DataTable();
        adap2.Fill(data2);

        MessageBox.Show("Project Details Save...");
        clear();
        refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the relationship work when you are not passing the primary key of inserted record as the foreign key?

Comment: can you help me how to pass it.  thank you im just new im having trouble

Comment: What column are you using for foreign key reference?

Comment: Aside... instead of concatenating tainted user data into the middle of your SQL queries learn to use parameterized queries with [`SqlParameter`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) via the `SqlDataAdapter`'s [`SelectCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand). Otherwise if anybody were to pass in `'; drop table tbl_project --` via `textID.Text` you're going to have a bad day.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you so much for the idea sir. yeah im learning it the stored procedure and cmd. parameters.  i just want to know how the sql adapter stored PK and FKey

Comment: @JamshaidK. Im my first main table id is the primary key second is projectid FKey  columnname is projectid

Comment: @MusicBuddy where are you passing your Project Id when creating the expense row?

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will get you the last inserted ID

Comment: @Charlieface, you cannot tell if the op is using an Identity column or not.

Comment: It appears `CONTRACT_ID` is the primary/foreign key between these two tables, however that is unclear, and it's also unclear if it's an `IDENTITY` column

Comment: Yes and contract_id is being passed from a textbox it appears from the code.

Comment: "There is no error in this code." Clarification: There IS an error if it's not doing what it's supposed to do. For debugging help we need more information. Please read "[mre]".

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've provided, it seems you are creating a value in two tables based on `Contract_Id` column and you are checking if the record already exists, you do not insert the records, otherwise you post the records.

Since, I cannot see the relationship between `tbl_project` and `tbl_expense`, I assume you are trying to insert `Contract_Id` as a foreign key in both the tables.

If that is the case, then I would suggest use below version of the code.

```cs
public void InsertIfNotExists()
{
    if (textID.Text == "" && textProject.Text == "" && textAmount.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Details..!");
    }
    else
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionString)) // Pass DbConnectionString for your SQL server instance
        {
            var query = @"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_project WHERE Contract_ID = @Contract_ID)
BEGIN
    -- Here we are checking if the row already exists for the variable @Contract_ID
    INSERT INTO tbl_project (Contract_ID, Contract_Amount, Contractor, Project_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Year, Address, Remarks, Status)
    VALUES (@Contract_ID, @Contract_Amount, @Contractor, @Project_Name, @Start_Date, @End_Date, @Year, @Address, @Remarks, @Status);
    -- We are inserting the values since Contract_ID was not matched in the database.

    INSERT INTO tbl_expense (CONTRACT, CONTRACT_ID, CONTRACTOR, PROJECT_STATUS, COVERED_PERIOD, END_PERIOD, PROJECT_AMOUNT)
    VALUES (@CONTRACT, @CONTRACT_ID, @CONTRACTOR, @PROJECT_STATUS, @COVERED_PERIOD, @END_PERIOD, @PROJECT_AMOUNT);
    -- We are inserting expense based on Contract_ID
END;
"
            ;
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contract_ID", textID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contract_Amount", textAmount.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contractor", textContract.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Name", textProject.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End_Date", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", textYear.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textAddress.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", textOthers.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", comboBox5.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRACT", textProject.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRACTOR", textContract.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_STATUS", comboBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COVERED_PERIOD", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_PERIOD", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_AMOUNT", textAmount.Text);

                connection.Open();

                var rA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();

                MessageBox.Show(rA > 0 ? "Data Successfully saved!" : "Data already exists!");
                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, we are formulating the SQL Statement in a way, that you do not have to fetch and compare and then post to the database, saves you from the round trips for a simple operation.

Also, you'll notice, we are using parameterized query, where we are passing the parameters in the SQL statement, as mentioned in the comments by @Always Learning, it is a good thing from guys who try to mess around with your database, this will prevent SQL Injections.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong. Yeah i try the contract id as my foreign key. But since the input of the user has a string value the database wont allow the relationship. So i decided to put projectid to get the id in the maintable as identifier. In the code above will this insert the id value on the projectid?.

Comment: Can you put an update to your question and mention the changes and code in your question for a better understanding?

Comment: what i did is i put a project id in my 2nd table and use it as an indentifier since the auto increment wont save in the project id i declare an automatic row counting which tell the system it is the id the must be save to the project id. after save it will pair now.

Comment: It is always a good idea to use an auto increment id instead of counting the rows yourself. Because when your table reaches millions of records, it has to count till million then assign the id and count is a costly operation to do on database.